# Pandas.read_excel throws "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to read in an excel file with the exact same parameters and setup as countless files before. However this one is refused by Pandas.

Sheetid and headerrow are 0 in this case. The file is of type xlsx. I tried saving as xls, but it didn't help.

This is also the row which raises the error:

```
inputframe = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=sheetid, header=headerrow)
```

Error:

```
in _parse_excel
data[header] = _trim_excel_header(data[header])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is a screenshot of the header and first few rows of the excel file in question:

[image: Excel file header and first rows]

I know that there are some empty cells in the file but that hasn't caused any problems in the past. Also I am probably not allowed to share the whole file with you for a more detailled analysis. Have to ask my boss first.

Comment: Is `headerrow` an `int` or `str`?

Comment: Yeah, I think headerrow doesn't contain what you think. Also, it defaults to 0, so better to leave it unspecified unless you have a true reason not to.

Comment: @bkd, did you manage to solve this? If so, please share you findings with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. headerrow was getting strings instead of ints for that one case.

Thanks to AKS and Shovalt for pointing me in the right direction.